# Why runState signature has only state argument?

Tags: haskell, state, monads

*A real-life example: If I'm in a good mood('good state'), when manager asks me about estimates, I give him a solid answer, but dares he to do that 3 times **in a row**, without some free snacks in between, my mood changes(I get to 'bad state') and the next 3 times he approaches I ask him not to disturb me with any of his nonsense.*

Here's a log of my usual day:

```
                             [ Mood: Good, Patience: 3 ]  -- 11:00 am, I'm happy
ESTIMATE -> "bla bla 6",     [ Mood: Good, Patience: 2 ]
ESTIMATE -> "bla bla 1",     [ Mood: Good, Patience: 1 ]
Cookies! -> "",              [ Mood: Good, Patience: 3 again! ]
ESTIMATE -> "bla bla 7",     [ Mood: Good, Patience: 2 ]
ESTIMATE -> "bla bla 2",     [ Mood: Good, Patience: 1 ]
ESTIMATE -> "bla bla 9",     [ Mood: BAD , Patience: -2 ] -- Enough!
ESTIMATE -> "Need a break!"  [ Mood: BAD , Patience: -1 ]
ESTIMATE -> "Deploynig!",    [ Mood: BAD , Patience: 0 ]
ESTIMATE -> "Lunch time!",   [ Mood: Good, Patience: 3 ]  -- Ok he needs me..
ESTIMATE -> "bla bla 6",     [ Mood: Good, Patience: 2 ]
...
```

Now this model of me at work seems to fit the `State` Monad.

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

But how do I do this? The signature has room for a state, which in my case is `(Mood,Patience)`, and not for input (`ESTIMATE` or `Cookies`). It's like I'm supposed to answer without even listening!

So my question is: **How do I make not only Stateful but also Argumentful computation with `State` monad of Haskell?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A stateful computation gets an input, a state and returns an output and a new state. So the type will be `input -> state -> (state, output)`.

The `runState` is just a partially applied stateful computation that has already taken its inputs.

Note also that when you compose stateful functions (i.e. when you use the `>>=` bind operator or `do` notation) you do exactly this: you supply the inputs as expression and the bind is responsible for passing around only the *state*.

You can call `get` without using its return value, but then it gets lost. If you want to make use of it you have to use `value <- get` and then provide the `value` as an explicit input for the next stateful computation. The bind only comes into play when passing the state around.

---

Practical example: consider the function:

```
doStuff :: Int -> State Int Int
doStuff x = do
    val <- get
    put $ val+x+1
    return 0
```

The `doStuff` type has exactly the pattern `input -> state -> (state, output)`. But the `input` part is represented by the `x` argument.
Once you provide `x` you get something of type `state -> (state, output)` which is exactly what `runState` represents.

So you don't actually need the arguments for stateful actions because you can partially apply them beforehand to obtain "pure stateful computations that have no input" (those are scary quotes).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're looking for is not `State` but `StateT`, a *monad transformer* that adds statefulness to an existing monad.

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT (s -> m (a, s))
```

Given a state of type `s` , a `StateT s m a` action returns an `m` action that, when run, produces a result and a new state. `StateT s` is an instance of `MonadTrans`:

```
instance MonadTrans (StateT s) where
  --lift :: Monad m => m a -> StateT s m a
  lift ma = StateT $
    \s -> ma >>= \a -> pure (a, s)
```

Further, if `m` is a `Monad`, then so is `StateT s m`.

So if you want to take "input" within some context (e.g., `IO`), you are free to do so:

```
do
  s <- get
  input <- lift getLine
  when (annoying input && annoyed s) $ put Angry
```

For `IO` in particular, it's usually better to use `liftIO`, which can lift through a whole stack of transformers.