# Haskell State Monad - What would the input to lamba \s -> ... be?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

In the tutorial [Learn You a Haskell - chapter 'for-a-few-monads-more', section 'The State monad'](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more), it lists the following to define the State Monad:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }

instance Monad (State s) where  
    return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)  
    (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                        (State g) = f a  
                                    in  g newState
```

Just need an answer to a simple question: What would the input to \s be (since State h = a function that takes a state and outputs a tuple (result, newState); implying that input to \s would just be that function)? Examples welcome

Comment: `s` is the current state, the function wrapped by the `State` newtype returns the result and new state.

Comment: But where is the 'current state' coming from? Is it coming from the first line of the definition: `instance Monad (State s)`? Implying the input is that 's'? Need a cold-hard answer using the definition itself.

Comment: No, there is also a `runState` function which takes the initial state and the computation to run e.g. `runState (return 1) "state" => (1, "state")`

Comment: The current state has to be provided from outside. A value of type `State s a` can be seen as a machine _requiring_ a current state `s`, and modifying it while also returning a value of type `a`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why runState signature has only state argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188080/why-runstate-signature-has-only-state-argument)

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a value of `State s a` as being a computation which depends on some state parameter which is provided when the computation is run. You can do this by simply unwrapping the contained function and calling it e.g.

```
runState (return 1) "state"
=> (1, "state")
```

Comment: @SoyTeins - What do you agree with? I edited the answer in response to the comment so it no longer applies.

Answer (score 1):

You can picture `return x` as meaning "Give me a state, and I'll give you back that state and x". Then you can think of `x >>= f1` as "Give me a state, and I'll give that to `x`; once it returns a state and a value, I'll give those to `f` and pass what `f` gives me on to you."

---

Here's an analogy with function composition:

```
f, g, h :: a -> a
j = f . g . h :: a -> a
```

`j` is a function that takes an `a`, and returns an `a`. Along the way, that value is first given to `h`, whose output goes to `g`, whose output goes to `f`, whose output is returned.

---

Look at "composition" of functions that return `State` values.

```
f', g', h' :: a -> State s a
j' a = return a >>= h' >>= g' >>= f'
```

Think of `State` as being a way of "hiding" a function argument. You could compose them manually like this:

```
f'', g'', h'' :: a -> s -> (a, s)
-- We could make this point-free by leaving h curried, but this
-- is nicely consistent.
j'' a s = (uncurry f'') . (uncurry g'') . (uncurry h'') $ (a, s)
```

but the `State` monad effectively does that for you with its implementation of `>>=`.

Note that `j'` only takes an initial value, while `j''` takes an initial value *and* an initial state. That's because the function that would take that state for `j'` is still wrapped up in a `State` value; we use `runState` to retrieve that function so that an initial state can be supplied to the first function in the stack.

```
(runState j') s0  -- parentheses optional, shown for emphasis
```